# add/remove class of multiple li in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I have list as below...

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

Now, when a particular `li` is clicked, I want the `active` class to be added to the same and remove `active` class from the rest of the `li` elements. Also, when the same `li` is clicked again I want to remove `active` class.

How, can i do this using `ng-click` and `ng-class`?

Comment: Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41699215/add-remove-class-of-multiple-li-in-angularjs) and show us what you have tried. So we can start from that to discuss you issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check the below example:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.setMaster = function(section) {
    $scope.selected = section;
  }

  $scope.isSelected = function(section) {
    return $scope.selected === section;
  }
}]);
```

```css
.active {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="i in ['One', 'Two', 'Three']" ng-class="{active : isSelected(i)}">
        <a ng-click="setMaster(i)">{{i}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <hr> {{selected}}
</div>
```