# Param in $routeParams is undefined but $routeParams not

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In code above, the first console.log returns undefined

But the second return a object with `cpf` property is set. Why ?

My URL: `http://xxxxxxx/#!/cpf/68473303253`

My Module

```
angular.module('welcomeback').controller('welcomeback', ['$scope', '$location', '$routeParams', function($scope, $location, $routeParams){

console.log('First console log');
console.log($routeParams.cpf);
console.log('Second console log');  
console.log($routeParams);
```

[image: $routeParams]

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/Exbherhe6TNYb9t5ThfL

Comment: Please, can you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41699215/add-remove-class-of-multiple-li-in-angularjs)?

Comment: @Andrea Follow this plunker with a minimal example [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/Exbherhe6TNYb9t5ThfL)

Comment: look the console log

Comment: Please provide the $routeProvider definition

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky In plunker  https://plnkr.co/edit/Exbherhe6TNYb9t5ThfL in app.config.js have the router definition

Comment: Try adding a main, basic "parent" controller that wraps the whole app with a base "/" route. Have that template implement the `<ng-view></ng-view>` directive. Update your routes to specify the controller and a template of valid HTML for each route. Finally add some links links matching those routes. See if you're still getting the undefined.

Comment: But why the console.log($routeParams) show the cpf property, But i can't call console.log($routeParams.cpf) ?

Comment: How do you solve this issue? Now i am having the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Because the route change is still under process when the controller loads and the first console is printed.

From Angular:

> Note that the $routeParams are only updated after a route change
>   completes successfully. This means that you cannot rely on
>   $routeParams being correct in route resolve functions. Instead you can
>   use $route.current.params to access the new route's parameters.

Comment: But even reversing the order of console.log's do not get the cpf property.
I updated the plunker demonstrating this concept.

Note that cpf property is already there

Comment: the console.log($routeParams) show the cpf property, But i can't call console.log($routeParams.cpf)

Comment: You see the property,but that doesn't mean it's value is defined